# Given a $2 \times 2$ matrix $B$ that satisfies $B^2=3B-2I$, find the eigenvalues of $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

> Given a $2 \times 2$ matrix $B$ that satisfies $B^2=3B-2I$, find the eigenvalues of $B$.

My attempt:

Let $v$ be an eigenvector for B, and $\lambda$ it's corresponding eigenvalue. Also, let $T$ be the linear transformation (not that this is exactly necessary for the question, but just added it in for my understanding.) Therefore,

$$T(v) = Bv = \lambda v$$

Now I'm unsure how to incorporate this information into the quadratic equation given above since by matrix / vector arithmetic isn't extremely solid. Thanks!

Comment: Two words: Cayley and Hamilton.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Haven't heard of Cayley ever, and the only Hamiton I know is a Hamilton path from graph theory

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Oh, wow, I just did some research - so the $P(\lambda) = det(A-\lambda I)=0$ I've been doing this whole time is called the Cayley-Hamilton theorem?

Comment: @Programmer: Not really, but it is related to that.  What you have been doing in solving the characteristic equation is finding the eigenvalues.  The Cayley-Hamilton theorem is something else, saying that if you plug your whole matrix (not just eigenvalues) into the characteristic equation, it gives the zero matrix.  For example, if you had a characteristic equation for $A$ of $\lambda^2 -3\lambda +2=0$, then the Cayley-Hamilton theorem implies that $A^2-3A+2=0$.   This fact isn't really used in solving this problem; we can't know what the characteristic equation is from the given info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue for $B$, with eigenvector $v$. Note that $B^2v=BBv=B(\lambda v)=\lambda^2v$.  Apply each side of your equation $B^2=3B-2I$ to the vector $v$ to get $\lambda^2 v= (3\lambda -2)v$, or $(\lambda^2-3\lambda +2)v=0$.  If a scalar times a nonzero vector is the zero vector, then the scalar is $0$, so $\lambda^2-3\lambda +2=(\lambda -1)(\lambda -2) =0$.  This means that the set of eigenvalues of $B$ is a subset of $\{1,2\}.$  It is impossible to determine which subset from the information given, as diagonal matrix examples show.

Comment: Hi Jonas, how does $B^2v=BBv=B(\lambda v)=\lambda^2v$?

Comment: @Programmer: Which of those $3$ equations do you not understand?

Comment: A bit confused how $B(\lambda v)=\lambda^2 v$, since $B=\lambda v$, doesn't $B (\lambda v)=\lambda^2 v^2$? But of course, I don't really understand how arithmetic operations work with vectors/matrices. Could you please instruct me on the rules, thanks!

Comment: @Programmer: There is no $v^2$ that makes sense in this context, and $B=\lambda v$ is wrong. It is correct that $Bv =\lambda v$.  It is also the case that in general $A(\lambda v) = \lambda Av$.  Being able to "pull out scalars" like this is one of the properties of linearity, and multiplying by a matrix is a linear transformation.  So $B(\lambda v) = \lambda Bv = \lambda \cdot \lambda v = \lambda^2 v$.

Answer (score 3):

Define $p(x) = (x-1)(x-2)$. You have $p(B) = 0$. Hence, the minimal polynomial of $B$ divides $p$. So, your eigenvalues are in $\{1,2\}$.